# How to Get notified from intentservice after completion of task?

Tags: android, android-intent

well i'm following this [link](http://androidhotel.wordpress.com/2012/01/08/a-simple-notification-system-with-the-intentservice-part-ii/)

even added Broadcast reciver as shown in the above link. but i's not notifying about the completion of the task,I want to run some activity after completion of this Intent service.
can any one pls help me out.

i'm getting the error as follow :

```
Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent 
{ act=com.saaranga.services.GetTaxonomy.DATA_RETRIEVED 
cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] (has extras) } 
from com.saaranga.lib (pid=1089, uid=10034) 
equires com.saaranga.services.Permissions.SEND_SIMPLE_NOTIFICATIONS 
due to receiver com.saaranga.lib/com.saaranga.services.ServiceReciver
```

In intentService i have initialized :

```
public static final String ACTION_NOTIFY="com.saaranga.services.GetTaxonomy.DATA_RETRIEVED";

private void sendSimpleBroadcast(int count)
{
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();

    broadcastIntent.setAction(GetTaxonomy.ACTION_NOTIFY);
    broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    broadcastIntent.putExtra(PARAM_OUT_COUNT, count);
//    broadcastIntent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), getClass());
    sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent, Permissions.SEND_SIMPLE_NOTIFICATIONS);
}
```

and created a permission class :

```
package com.saaranga.services;

public class Permissions {
public static final String SEND_SIMPLE_NOTIFICATIONS =  "com.saaranga.services.Permissions.SEND_SIMPLE_NOTIFICATIONS";}
```

And in manifest file :

```
 <permission 
    android:name="com.saaranga.services.Permissions.SEND_SIMPLE_NOTIFICATIONS"
    android:label="permission to send simple notifications"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.PERSONAL_INFO"
    android:protectionLevel="normal" />

<service
        android:name="com.saaranga.services.GetTaxonomy"
        android:enabled="true" 
        android:exported="true">
</service>

<receiver android:name="com.saaranga.services.ServiceReciver"
              android:exported="true"
              android:permission="com.saaranga.services.Permissions.SEND_SIMPLE_NOTIFICATIONS">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.saaranga.services.GetTaxonomy.DATA_RETRIEVED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
         </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

even added Broadcast reciver as soon in the above link. but i's not notifying about the completion of the task,I want to run some activity after completion of this Intent service.
can any one pls help me out.

Answer (score 5):

**Step 1:**

In MainActivity.class

```
private ResponseReceiver receiver;
//register reciver

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ResponseReceiver.ACTION_RESP);
    filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    receiver = new ResponseReceiver();
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

**Step 2:**
Sub class in an MainActivity.class which extents BroadcastReceiver.

```
    public class ResponseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String ACTION_RESP = "com.saaranga.intent.action.MESSAGE_PROCESSED";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "download complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

**Step 3:**
In IntentService :

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
    broadcastIntent.setAction(ResponseReceiver.ACTION_RESP);
    broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
}
```

This code works fine for me.
Cheers.

Comment: Good, simple instructions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my main Activity I have defined a status flag

```
private final Handler LoginHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message loginmessage) {
            Bundle receivedData = loginmessage.getData();
            loginStatus = receivedData.getString("status");

                   if(loginStatus.equals("done")){
                     //do something
                   }else{
                     //do something
                    }
                 };
            };
```

In the intent service I sent a value 'done' if the work was done and 'connectionerror' if there was any error

```
try {


            if (LoginBundle != null) {

                Messenger LoginMessenger = (Messenger) LoginBundle
                        .get("LOGINMESSENGER");
                Message LoginMessage = Message.obtain();

                LoginBundle.putString("status", "Done");

                try {
                    LoginMessenger.send(LoginMessage);
                }

                catch (android.os.RemoteException e1) {
                    Log.w("Message Not Sent", e1);
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            Bundle LoginBundle = intent.getExtras();
            Message LoginMessage = Message.obtain();
            Messenger LoginMessenger = (Messenger) LoginBundle
                    .get("LOGINMESSENGER");
            LoginBundle.putString("status", "Connection Error");
            LoginMessage.setData(LoginBundle);

            try {
                LoginMessenger.send(LoginMessage);
            }

            catch (android.os.RemoteException e1) {
                Log.w("Message Not Sent", e1);
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.w("Unhandled", ex);
        }
```

so in the main actvity if I get any of the reply I can detect that the intent service is done its work.

Hope you understood my way of identifying the state of the service.